# Getting data from checkbox made by bootstrap form generator

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a set up checkboxes that look like the below

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="environment">Environment</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox inline" for="environment-0">
            <input type="checkbox" name="environment['com1']" id="environment-0" value="1">
            Com1
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox inline" for="environment-1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="environment['com2']" id="environment-1" value="1">
            Com2
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox inline" for="environment-2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="environment['com3']" id="environment-2" value="1">
            Com3
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I return the `$_POST` data I get the following

```
array(7) {
  ["environment"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["'com1'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["'com2'"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
```

I'm somewhat new to dealing with arrays and am confused how to reference the string found in `com1`. I'm trying `$envCom1 = $_POST["environment['com1']"];` but getting the error `Undefined index: environment['com1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var =  $_POST["environment"]
```

is an array. So you should access value with 'com1' index of this array like,

```
$var =  $_POST["environment"];
echo $var["'com1'"];
```

OR

```
echo $_POST["environment"]["'com1'"];
```

Comment: ah, that makes sense. And a quick follow up, how should I change the form to remove the single quotes from `com1` in the `$_POST` data? It seems a bit redundant?

Comment: remove single quotes for the keys of environment array in the input form. 
change name="environment['com1']" to name="environment[com1]" for an example